# Does Transformations combining affect Action execution time in PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark code that takes multiple input dataframes and produce one dataframe as an output.
I perform many spark transformations (map, filter, joins, reducebykey...)  on the DFs but NO spark action. The only action I perform is at the end of the code (count() of the output df). 
the code is too long to put it in here, but it looks like this:

```
df1 = HiveContext.sql("select * from db.table1")
df2 = HiveContext.sql("select * from db.table2")
...
...
dfN = HiveContext.sql("select * from db.tableN")

#map transformation
#join transformations
#filter transformation
...
resultDF.count()
```

So I have two questions : 
1. Does combining multiple transformations affect Action execution duration in PySpark ?
2. since I perform only one action at the end, would cashing improve this code performance?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does combining multiple transformations affect Action execution duration in PySpark ?

Yes.

> 2. since I perform only one action at the end, would cashing improve this code performance?

No, because transformations are lazily evaluated until you perform an action.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was a very helpful article :)